# Lambda expression returns method?

Tags: c#, lambda

Hi I do not understand statement that "lambda expressions return methods" that I read in a book I currently study.
On MSDN I did not find anything which could help me.

Comment: It would really help if you'd give more context than four words. A complete sentence, or ideally a whole paragraph would make it a lot easier to guess what the author meant.

Comment: Trying to be non technical - think of a lambda as an (anonymous) function within your method (a bit like 'nesting'). It then needs to be called just like any other explicit method - the act of assigning a variable to the lambda doesn't invoke the method, just keeps a 'reference' to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#/.NET you can save a reference to method in variable. This is done using delegates.

Lambda expressions can created a method, that can be saved in variable or returned from method.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong,what it means is: Lamda Expression can return a function delegate

```
Func<in T, out TResult>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score -1):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163362.aspx